# Rabbit prefetch

Tags: java, spring, amqp, spring-amqp

I use spring amqp with rabbitmq. I want get one message without prefetch. 
I configured with

```
      SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(rabbitConnectionFactory());
    container.setQueueNames(
            ProjectConfigs.getInstance().get_RABBIT_TASK_QUEUE()
    );
    container.setMessageListener(taskListener());
    container.setConcurrentConsumers(1);
    container.setPrefetchCount(1);
    container.setTxSize(1);
    return container;
```

How to disable prefetch and get only one message/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`prefetch` simply controls how many messsages the broker allows to be outstanding at the consumer at a time. When set to 1, this means the broker will send 1 message, wait for the ack, then send the next.

It defaults to 1. Setting it to 0 will mean the broker will send unlimited messages to the consumer, regardless of acks.

If you only want one message and then stop, you shouldn't use a container, you can use one of the `RabbitTemplate.receive()` methods.

Comment: Hmm, how i can know exist messages in queue without infinity loop? Timers ?

Comment: Maybe you should explain your use case (what you are trying to achieve). Why do you care whether messages exist? With the listener container, your application is message-driven.

Comment: I want create linux system service. If queue not contain messages, the  idle, otherwise if income 10 messages. demon get one message, process it, after get next message.

Answer (score 0):

I try do it with Spring AMQP

```
@Bean
public MessageListener taskListener() {
    return new MessageListener() {
        public void onMessage(Message message) {
            try {
                LOGGER.info(new String(message.getBody(), "UTF-8"));
                Converter converter = new Converter();
                converter.startConvert(new String(message.getBody(), "UTF-8"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.error(getStackTrace(e));
            }
        }
    };
}
```